# jQueryUI Tabs - Scroll content only

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, tabs

How do I keep the tab headers visible always when there is large content. I wish the content to scroll, but the tab headers to not.

In this screen shot I have set the page to be 100% H and W and want scroll bars to scroll content only.

As you can see the scroll bar affects the tab headers too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set max height for your tab container, and add css style **overflow-y** to it.